# Search within a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with the results from infra sound detectors but sometimes they have glitches so the data points are recorded as '0'. This is worthless data. I want to be able to search the file for '0', count them and print out that result.

All I have been able to do so far is search the file for '0' and get a true/false answer.

This is my code:

```
def findzero( fname ): 
    if os.path.isfile(fname): 
        f = open( fname ) 
        s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 
        if s.find('0') != -1: 
            print 'true' 
        else: 
            print '' 
    return;
```

Comment: And what does your code look like that does the search? How big are these files? Does the `'0'` appear on a line by their own, or is this binary data or text with long lines? What are the possibilities for false-positives (e.g. valid data point might be `'10420'` and should not be counted as 2 `'0'` values)?

Comment: This is the code that does the search:                             def findzero( fname ):
 if os.path.isfile(fname):
  f = open( fname )
  s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
  if s.find('0') != -1:
      print 'true'
 else: 
  print ''
 return;

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add details like that.

Comment: The files are all about 35 MB. The 0 appears on a line of its own, but there are definitely possibilities for false positives.

Comment: What deeper investigation would tell you that there is a false positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan the file line by line, counting the lines with just `'0'`:

```
def countzero(fname): 
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            return sum(line.strip() == '0' for line in f)
    except IOError:
        # not a file we can read
        return None
```

The Python `bool` type is a subclass of `int`, and `True` is equal to 1, `False` is 0, so you can sum the booleans to get a count.

If you needed a *percentage*, you need to count lines and 0-counts separately:

```
def count_zeros_and_lines(fname): 
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            zeros = total = 0
            for line in f:
                if line.strip() == '0':
                    zeros += 1
                total += 1
            return zeros, total
    except IOError:
        # not a file we can read
        return None
```

This returns a count of zeros, and a total line count.

Comment: That has worked, thank you. Just one more thing, need to turn calcilate what percentage of the data points are 0. What would be the best way to add to the code above to do this?

Comment: @user3755536: what is 100% then? The number of lines?

Comment: yeah it is basically the number of lines. Sorry I am not being clear enough with my questions, it is really difficult to know what details to put in.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask about the line count bit because I already know what the line count is. This is exactly the help I needed though so thank you.